# Exit Code history and best practice

Tags: windows, exit-code

I am finding a bunch of duplicate error codes when dealing with Autodesk installs and uninstalls. For example

**3010** ERROR_SUCCESS_REBOOT_REQUIRED

**-2147021886** ERROR_SUCCESS_REBOOT_REQUIRED

and

**1618** ERROR_INSTALL_ALREADY_RUNNING

**-2147023278** ERROR_INSTALL_ALREADY_RUNNING

I am curious, is one or the other the "newer" approach, or has Microso0ft always had parallel and redundant exit codes? And in either case, is one or the other the preferred approach? I am beginning to build my own installers, and I want to be sure I am using the correct sequence if there is such a thing. If there is no best practice I feel like the positive numbers are better for logs being shorter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows user mode, the error codes are used in two forms mainly. One is [HRESULT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/0642cb2f-2075-4469-918c-4441e69c548a) and another one is [Win32 error codes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/18d8fbe8-a967-4f1c-ae50-99ca8e491d2d). HRESULT is generally used in [COM programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) and indicated as HEX value. Methods return `S_OK` (Zero) after success, negative for failure (starting with 0x8). Win32 error codes are integers in between 0 and 65535 (`2^16 - 1`). Both can be converted to each other with some macros specified in `WinError.h` header file in Windows SDK. Here are the sample:

```c
#define FACILITY_WIN32 7

#define __HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(x) \
((HRESULT)(x) <= 0 ? ((HRESULT)(x)) : ((HRESULT) (((x) & 0x0000FFFF) | (FACILITY_WIN32 << 16) | 0x80000000)))

#define HRESULT_CODE(hr) ((hr) & 0xFFFF)
```

For the above example,the conversion will be like this:

```
-2147021886 = 0x80070BC2 = (0x80070BC2 & 0xFFFF) = 0xBC2 = 3010
-2147023278 = 0x80070625 = (0x80070625 & 0xFFFF) = 0x652 = 1618
```

Both of this error codes defined in `WinError.h` header file. If you are doing some COM programming then use HRESULT (installer uses COM a lot). If you are using Win32 APIs then use Win32 error codes (returned by GetLastError). Both error code formats can be passed to `FormatMessage()` to get equivalent error message (like `strerror()` in Linux world).

#### Further readings:

- [MS Docs: 2.1 HRESULT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/0642cb2f-2075-4469-918c-4441e69c548a)
- [MS Docs: 2.2 Win32 Error Codes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/18d8fbe8-a967-4f1c-ae50-99ca8e491d2d)
- [MS Docs: 2.1.2 HRESULT From WIN32 Error Code Macro](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/0c0bcf55-277e-4120-b5dc-f6115fc8dc38)
- [The Old New Thing: How do I convert an HRESULT to a Win32 error code?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20061103-07/?p=29133)

Comment: So, for a standard installer for a desktop program (like AutoCAD, or Word, or Photoshop) Win32 seems like the right answer, is that right. Or would some of the components of those programs be considered COM objects while the overall program is Win32?

Comment: Use what the function returns and consult MS Docs.

Comment: I guess what I mean is, if I was doing my own app, I would use Win32 codes not HRESULT. The latter is "correctly" for use when creating interprocess communication components, not regular desktop apps.

Comment: No one restricts you to use anyone of them because both of them convertible to each other. In my _opinion_, Win32 is better because as a human we understand decimals better :)

Comment: I almost wish Microsoft WOULD enforce some standards. Autodesk is totally inconsistent with which flavor they use, which is really the worst option. I agree, for myself I'll stick with Win32, both for positive numbers and smaller numbers. Both are easier to quickly grasp.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that those pairs of error exit codes represent  the same errors, respectively:

```
$errCodes = 3010, -2147021886, 1618, -2147023278

foreach ($errCode in $errCodes) {
    '{0,12} 0x{1:x8}' -f $errCode, $errCode
}
```

> ```
>         3010 0x00000bc2
>  -2147021886 0x80070bc2
>         1618 0x00000652
>  -2147023278 0x80070652
> ```

```
foreach ($errCode in $errCodes) {
    '{0,12} 0x{1:x4}' -f $errCode, ($errCode -band 0xFFFF)
}
```

> ```
>         3010 0x0bc2
>  -2147021886 0x0bc2
>         1618 0x0652
>  -2147023278 0x0652
> ```